# Installing Phalcon 1.3.4 incubator

Tags: composer-php, phalcon

I am trying to install the incubator of Phalcon 1.3.4 as per the documentation at https://github.com/phalcon/incubator

```
{
"require": {
    "phalcon/incubator": "v1.2.5"
}
```

in the composer.json.
I have phalcon 1.3.4 installed already. But when I try to update the composer, I get the following error:

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Installation request for phalcon/incubator v1.2.5 -> satisfiable by phalcon/incubator[v1.2.5].
    - phalcon/incubator v1.2.5 requires ext-phalcon 1.2.5 -> the requested PHP extension phalcon has the wrong version (1.3.4) installed.

How can this be installed for 1.3.4 version?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need a specific version, you could just go with the latest. This works fine for me.

```
{
    "require": {
        "phalcon/incubator" : "*"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the version of "v1.2.5" -> "v1.3.5" for Phalcon 1.x.
The latest version of incubator is for Phalcon 2.x.

> If you are still using Phalcon 1.3.x, create a composer.json with the following instead:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phalcon/incubator": "v1.3.5"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the specified version in place of the one you are using.
Or you can put a * to use the newer version.

Then just run the **'composer install'**